# What's TypeORM's default table column name rule?

Tags: typeorm

In a project using TypeORM, after prepareing `ormconfig.ts` and did a database migration, it created this type of column in the table:

> deletedAt

But generally it should be this type

> deleted_at

Is there a default setting for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is to simply use the name of the field with the `@Column()` annotation as name in the database.

If I use

```
@Column() deletedAt: number;
```

following migration is created:

```
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "public"."test" ADD "deletedAt" integer NOT NULL`);
```

And for this

```
@Column() deleted_at: number;
```

you will get this migration

```
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "public"."test" ADD "deleted_at" integer NOT NULL`);
```

EDIT: At least this is true for a postgres database with typeorm 0.3.6. I must admit that I don't know if there is dependency to the database used, since I don't know the limitations. Maybe there is a database out there which does not support case sensitive column names.

Comment: Thank you. For postgres database it's good enough.